# why $P^* = P_1 \cup P_2$? Why not $P^* = P_1 \cap P_2?$

Tags: real-analysis

I have  some confusion on Baby Rudin book page No: $123$

> the partition  $P^*$  is a refinement of $P$  if  $P^* \supset P$
> ,
> Given tw0 partition $P_1$ and $P_2$ , we say that  $P^*$ is their  common  refinement  if $P^* = P_1 \cup P_2$

**My confusion** :

why $P^* = P_1 \cup P_2$? Why not $P^* = P_1 \cap P_2?$

My thinking:

Generally, I think Common means intersection

If $P^*$ is their common refinement.

Then  $P_1 \subset P^* $ and $P_2 \subset P^*$

Comment: Because $P_1 \cap P_2 \subseteq P_1, P_2$ but $P_1 \cup P_2 \supseteq P_1, P_2$. A refinement needs to be latter, not former.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do we have $P_1\subseteq P_1\cup P_2$ and $P_2\subseteq P_1\cup P_2$, or do we have $P_1\subseteq P_1\cap P_2$ and $P_2\subseteq P_1\cap P_2$? Which one works the way a refinement should?

$P_1$ has a lot of different refinements, and $P_2$ has a lot of different refinements. Some partitions happen to be refinements of both of them at the same time, and this is known as a common refinement. That doesn't mean that a common refinement can contain only the points that $P_1$ and $P_2$ have in common. A common refinement contains all points of $P_1$ and also all points of $P_2$. Does the union or the intersection accomplish this best?

Answer (score 1):

If you take the intersection you get less points, so a coarser partition. Just write an example with a few points and you'll see.

Comment: Can you provide a specific example?

Answer (score 1):

1. $P'$ is a refinement of $P$ if(f) $P \subset P'$.
2. A common refinement of $P_1$ and $P_2$ is a partition $P'$ such that $P_1 \subset P$ *and* $P_2 \subset P$.
   Note that $$P_1 \subset P \text{ and } P_2 \subset P \iff (P_1 \cup P_2) \subset P.$$

---

As an example, you can simply take the partitions $P_1 = \{0, 0.5, 1\}$ and $P_2 = \{0, 0.25, 1\}$ of $[0, 1]$.